# ClassNotFoundException while running maven in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run the maven in Jenkins, but getting:

```
...
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 7547
[Spider] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1/bin/java" C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.12.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.0\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.0/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main "C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.0" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.27.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.12.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12.jar" 7547
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Program
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

I see, that Jenkins is trying to find main class in `C:\Program`, what of course is wrong. But I cannot find where to change this setting. My script is working fine in IntelliJ, but not in Jenkins.

Any help is much apreciated.

Comment: It is probably occurring because of the way you have provided the Maven bin path. There's a space after `C:\Program` and after that it can't read the path. Try putting the Maven bin path inside double quotes `"C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin"`. It should work.

Comment: or you could try to configure the path using the variable `%programfiles%`, although I'm not sure if variables get expanded correctly here

Comment: Oh my God! I have spent so much time on this issue.. Exactly it was the path to Maven, but as you see in logs there was only `C:\Program`, which said nothing to me. Thank you very much @ANIL

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov you are welcome. Also, there is one more solution. You can use the following notation for the paths:

For 32bits: C:\Program Files (x86)\,  you can use c:\progra~2\ and for 64bits: C:\Program Files\,  you can use c:\progra~1\

Comment: Sure will do that @AndreiSuvorkov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because of the way you have declared your Maven bin path. There's a space after `C:\Program` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin` and that is causing the problem. Jenkins is looking for your Maven bin folder inside `C:\Program` which doesn't exist.

You can resolve it in two ways:

One, try putting your Maven bin path inside double quotes:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin"`

Or, you can use a more abstract approach as given below:

Use these notations for the paths:

For **32bits**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\`, you can use `c:\progra~2\`

For **64bits**: `C:\Program Files\`, you can use `c:\progra~1`